# generating intervals multiples of 10 between two numbers

Tags: javascript, math

I have two numbers like ESP1 and ESP2.

In my DB there are many data to the ESP1 & ESP2, ESP1 is minimum values and ESP2 is maximum value.

i need to generate intervals between those two number in multiplies of 10, for example.

ESP1 = 0 and ESP2 = 83

my result should be [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80].

how to write code for this in js

Comment: From the answers it's not clear what should happen when ESP1 is something like 11. Should the list start at 11 and and add ten, or start from 20?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `for` loop:

```
function generateIntervalsOf(interval, start, end) {
  const result = [];
  let current = start;

  while (current < end) {
    result.push(current);
    current += interval;
  }

  return result;
}

generateIntervalsOf(10, 0, 83) // [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either a `for` or `while` loop. There are two approaches you could take.

A: Brute force. Count up from the start number to the end number and store every multiple of ten.

```
const results = [];
for (let i = ESP1; i <= ESP2; i++) {
  if (i %10 === 0) {
    results.push(i);
  }
}
```

B: Cleverness. Brute force might be slow if you were doing this over a very large range. Instead of going through every single number, we only need the multiples of ten. So, in short, we just need the next multiple of ten after ESP1, and we add ten until we exceed ESP2.

e.g.

```
const results = [];
const floor = ESP1 + 10 - ESP1 % 10; 
// i.e. if ESP1 is 13, add 10 to get 23, and then subtract 3 to get 20
for(let i = floor; i < ESP2; i+= 10) {
  results.push(i);
}
```

If we ran this with ESP1 = 3 and ESP2 = 56, we would get the result `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`. This approach will go through 1/10 as many iterations as approach A, since we're counting by tens.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
const a = 0;
const b = 83;
const result = _.range(a, b, 1).filter(item => item%10 == 0);
console.log(result)
```